# Cycles rendering looks strange and simplified

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Here is my ViewPort rendering (which is good):

[image: ViewPortRendered]

But my Cycles Rendering looks like this:

[image: CylesRendering]

Any idea why this is happening? I'm new to blender so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we take a look at your render settings?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an accidental Layer Material override. Check if your active render layer has a material set in the data field indicated in red in this screenshot:

[image: Layer Override]

Such an override replaces every single material on the RenderLayer with the one selected. It's useful for adding custom AO passes, Clay Renders, or diagnostic renders.

Click the small <kbd>X</kbd> icon next to the material to remove the override, and you should be back to normal.

By the way: By default the viewport renderer does not take Render Layer modifications into account. That's why you get a different result between the two. You need to explicitly tell Blender to do this using this Toggle Button while a viewport render is running:

[image: Viewport Render Layer Override]